# How to solve this in java eclipse square of all numbers and sum

Tags: java, eclipse, math, sequence, square

Given the sequence of numbers: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], design a program that will square each number in the sequence and return the sum of all the squares added together.

i need help to do this in java any idea with outputs and comments

i currently have a half working solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class interview2 {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your squared number is: " + square(num));
    }
    public static int square(int num) 
    {
        return num * num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your half working solution.

Comment: Please share that half working solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            sum += square(i); /*you can use the power
            function e.g pow(i,2)*/
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

public static int square(int num) { return num * num; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it in terms of steps.

- you have an array.
- initialize a sum to 0;
- iterate over the numbers and compute their square
- add that value to sum.
- when done iterating over the numbers, print the sum.

Answer (score -1):

Well, here's a simple start...(update your *half working solution* that was never provided.)

```java
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i : numbers) {
     sum += i * i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```